# Add some string inside div tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to add some string or HTML tag inside div `#OL_Icon_63` using jQuery `.append()`, here's the example of code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#OL_Icon_63').append('HELLO WORLD');
});
```

But that's code won't work for me, I try to change the code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
       $('#OL_Icon_63').append('HELLO WORLD');
    });
});
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").hover(function() {
       $('#OL_Icon_63').append('HELLO WORLD');
    });
});
```

Two kinds of code work for me where I use `.hover()` and `.click()` after body tag, but i basically can not use the function like .append() or anything else without adding .hover() or .click() after $("body")
but when I use click or hover the string appeared repeatedly

Can anyone give me some example / opinion so that `.append()` jQuery function will work perfect for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution is using the fact javascript functions are objects, once the function clickAction is called it will set itself to a blank function after appending the text

**EDIT**
This does not work in jQuery due to the way it handles events, however it does contain a method called one()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clickAction = function(){
     $('div').append("Hello World");
  } 
    $("div").one("click",clickAction);
});​
```

Comment: I basically can not use the function without adding .hover() , .click() after $("body")
but when I use click or hover the string appeared repeatedly

Comment: i just try to change div to #OL_Icon_63 , but it doesn't work for me
Any another way, not use .click() or .hover(), so the string can open automatically when i'm not click or hover it ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i think the bottom div on .one() must be change to body :D
And your help is realy helped for me, so thank you for your help, i'm so very grateful :)

Comment: i have a more question againt, i'm just edit that code, but the hover function wouldn't work, is there are error or the code syntax is wrong? You can view here : http://pastebin.com/QpESh0C4 . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` instead:

```
$('#OL_Icon_63').text("hello world")
```

You are using append incorrectly. Append is for adding *elements* to the innerHTML of an element. `text` is for text, and `html` is for HTML

This will also replace all text in the element, so there will be no multiples.

Comment: I basically can not use the function without adding .hover() , .click() after $("body") but when I use click or hover the string appeared repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try without `$(document).ready` this works for me:

```
(function(){
    $('#OL_Icon_63').append('HELLO WORLD');
})();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tgzKQ/

Comment: Sorry, but that's code is still not working for me :) but i'm so very thanksfull about your answer
And about the downvote, i'm not give the downvote, but who the person so very cruel like that

Comment: Can you add more of your code to the example so we can see what else it's messing up your code?

Comment: I'm so very grateful you will be give me the answer if the code is mess or got some errors :) but the apps is still current inside my localhost :( but i will be upload it soon.